# Numero repetido en matriz

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber como podría hacer para que cuando el usuario me ingresa dos números iguales en la apuesta le tire error que no se pueden repetir dos números en una misma apuesta:

```
static bool Agregar(int[,] m, ref int tope) //agregar una apuesta
{
    bool disponible = true;
    bool repetido = true;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 5)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Write("\n" + "INGRESE NÚMERO (" + (i + 1) + ") : ");
            m[tope, i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            repetido = true;
            for (int x = 0; x < tope; x++)
            {
                if (m[tope, i] == m[tope, i])
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if (repetido)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("repe");
            }
            disponible = true;
            if (m[tope, i] >= 1 && m[tope, i] <= 48 && disponible == true)
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                disponible = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Número no disponible para apostar (1-48)");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Número incorrecto");
        }
    }
    tope++;
    return disponible;
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{

    nombres = new string[cantidad];
        int[,] matriz = new int[cantidad, 5];
        i
                while (!salir)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("PRIMER OBLIGATORIO");
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("1- AGREGAR UNA APUESTA");
                    Console.WriteLine("2- AGREGAR UNA APUESTA SORPRESA");
                    Console.WriteLine("3- ELIMINAR UNA APUESTA");
                    Console.WriteLine("4- NÚMEROS DE UN APOSTADOR");
                    Console.WriteLine("5- LISTADO COMPLETO DE APUESTAS");
                    Console.WriteLine("6- NÚMEROS QUE NO HAN ESTADO EN APUESTAS");
                    Console.WriteLine("7- SALIR");
                    try
                    {
                        Console.Write("INGRESE OPCIÓN (1-7) : ");
                        opcion = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("La opción es incorrecta (1-7)");
                    }
                    Console.Clear();
                    switch (opcion)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------");
                            Console.WriteLine("                   AGREGAR UNA APUESTA");
                            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
                            if (tope < nombres.Length)
                            {
                                    Console.Write("INGRESE NOMBRE : ");
                                    nombres[tope] = Console.ReadLine();
                                    if (nombres[tope] == "")
                                    {
                                        mensaje = mensaje + "Debe ingresar un nombre";

                                        if (mensaje == "")
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine("Nombre ingresado correctamente");
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine(mensaje);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else 
                                    {
                                        Agregar(matriz, ref tope);
                                        Console.WriteLine();
                                        Console.WriteLine("Se agrego correctamente su apuesta");
                                    }                            
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("No hay màs apuestas disponibes");
                            }
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
....
```

lo que intente hacer yo esta mal , por las dudas!

Comment: Hola, quisiera saber como podría hacer para que cuando el usuario me ingresa dos números iguales en la apuesta le tire error que no se pueden repetir dos números en una misma apuesta

Comment: bienvenido a StackOverflow. Lo primero que necesitamos por favor es que en lugar de una captura de pantalla, pegues el código que estas intentando para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Pásate por [ask]

Comment: en ningún momento evalúas repetido, por consecuente, siempre te dirá que está repetido. deberías recorrer la matriz comparando valores, en caso de que sean iguales, hacer que repetido sea verdadero.

Comment: @Francop Tambien, ya que hay varias preguntas al parecer sobre este mismo ejercicio con lo que supongo que es una tarea escolar, sería interesante saber que herramientas os dejan utilizar(LINQ? `Contains`...?

Comment: Bien disculpen es que es mi primer pregunta y no sabia bien como funcionaba, esas herramientas que nombraste no nos dejan utilizar

Comment: @L.Ronquillo como recorro la matriz comparando valores?

Comment: No te preocupes @Francop, nadie nace sabiendo por eso tratamos de explicarte.Si quieres puedes [edit] la pregunta y copiar el código que tienes hasta ahora :)

Comment: Muy bien ahí le agarre la mano, editado! Reitero yo lo que quiero es que el apostador no pueda ingresar dos números iguales en su apuesta, aclaro que lo que yo hice esta mal!

Comment: Bien,eso está mejor. Necesitamos alguna aclaración mas: en `m` en la primera dimensión hay un array por usuario,y en la segunda se almacenan los numeros para cada usuario? dos usuarios pueden tener el mismo número?

Comment: Voy a agregar el main para que te des cuenta de lo que me preguntaste, con respecto a que si dos usuarios pueden tener el mismo numero es que si, lo que no puede es un usuario tenes dos números iguales en su apuesta

Comment: Sería buena idea que hables con https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/42941/alejandro él también anda desarrollando algo similar. Saludos y bienvenido a SOes :D

Answer (score 2):

Bien, en el método que nos pones tienes varios problemas:

1. en lugar de guardar directamente en el array lo que ha introducido el usuario, debes meterlo en una variable temporal para comprobar si está repetido antes de meterlo: `var numeroIntroducido = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`
2. Una vez hecho esto, comprobar si el numero ya existe es sencillo. Simplemente, comparas el numero introducido con todos los que existen en el array,algo asi:

   ```
   repetido = false;
   for (int j=0;j<m.GetLength(1);j++)
   {
       if (m[tope,j]==numeroIntroducido)
       {
           repetido=true;
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Por otro lado, usar try/catch para comprobar si lo introducido es correcto no está bien, es mejor usar `Int32.TryParse`

Con todo esto, el código para comprobar si el numero esta repetido mas o menos quedaría asi:

```
bool repetido=true;
while (repetido)
{
     Console.Write("\n" + "INGRESE NÚMERO (" + (i + 1) + ") : ");
     int numeroIntroducido;
     if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out numeroIntroducido))
     {
           repetido = false;
           //en este bucle es donde se comprueba si el numero esta ya en el array
           for (int j=0;j<m.GetLength(1);j++)
           {
                 if (m[tope,j]==numeroIntroducido)
                 {
                     repetido=true;
                     break;
                 }
           }
           if(!repetido) 
           { 
               m[tope, i]=numeroIntroducido;
           }
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Número incorrecto");
     }
}
```

Te queda adaptar la comprobación de si está disponible y meterlo dentro del bucle que pide los 5 elementos.

Comment: voy a probar! , utilizo try and catch porque es lo que dimos en clase eso que me pasaste vos no lo hemos dado aun

Comment: En ese caso, usa el try/catch. Lo importante es que sigas la lógica de la comprobación de si `numeroIntroducido` está ya en el array. No quiero darte un código completo ya que se trata de que aprendais a pensar por vosotros mismo y a practicar la lógica de la programacion :)

Comment: Se entiende , muchas gracias y disculpa las molestias!

Comment: si yo saco el tope++; me deja agregar la cantidad de apuestas que quiera cuando al inicio del programa le indico cuantos clientes desean apostar, por ej si me dice que quiere agregar solo 2 clientes deberian ser dos personas las que pueda agregar pero al sacar el tope++; deja agregar mas personas que las solicitadas al inicio

Comment: Si, ahora que estoy viendo tu main tienes razon. lo normal sería que el tope lo incrementases en el main y no en el métod, pero ya que en el main no lo estas haciendo efectivamente debes hacerlo ahi.He editado la respuesta

Comment: como puedo hacer para mostrar los numeros que no han estado en apuestas, hay que tener en cuenta que van hasta el 48